# Copy value from a cell in one sheet to a cell in the last used Column in another sheet, if values in two other Columns' values match

Tags: vba, excel

This may not be possible using VBA. I have an Architectural drawings register which uses 1 row per drawing with individual columns for Drawing Number, Drawing Name, scale and paper size. Issued information is tracked from column "O" onwards.

When information is issued, the current revision of that information is marked under the date that it is being issued on.

The software we use to develop our drawing information contains data including the most current revision. What I am trying to do is export the drawing number and current revision values to excel and then automatically bring that information into the last issue date on the drawing register in the correct row.
I was hoping to ensure the correct row by searching the contents of [Sheet1 (000 MODELS, ACAD...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMeTX.png)  Column A with the contents of Sheet3 ("Revisions") Column A and when it finds a match on Sheet1, copy Sheet3's corresponding cell from column B into the matched rows' last column.

So far (Updated image):
I had previously updated a simplified version of the sheet, but have now uploaded the original version.

As you can see in the image of Sheet 1, there are two buttons. One that hides all issues before a prompted input date, and Update Revisions which doesn't work yet...

Sheet2 (List) is used purely for storing values used in macro calculations and data calcs (Don't have enough rep to post a 3rd link...). The last column number is recorded as a value in Sheet3 cell AA3 because of the findCol macro I use for the 'Hide/Show Old Issue Dates' button, which I'm hoping can be used for defining the column to copy the current revision to.  Columns AA and AJ store the information used in this macro.

[Sheet3 (revisions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efBoG.png) contains the exported drawing number and current revision for each drawing as exported from Revit. For the process I see it that this data should be copied in from the exported 'standalone' excel sheet, manipulated to populate the issue sheet with current revisions and is then deleted.

The piece of code that I'm having trouble with is where I'm trying to find a matching value in Column H on Sheet1 for the values in Sheet3. Where a match is found I want to copy the cell value from Sheet3 into the last column on the  corresponding row in Sheet1.

```
Sub updateRevs()
Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set r = Sheets("Revisions")
Dim d
d = 1
Dim j As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = r.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until IsEmpty(r.Range("A" & j))
For j = 1 To LastRow
    If r.Range("A" & d).Value = i.Range(j, 8).Value Then
        r.Range("B" & d).Copy
        i.Range(j, Sheet2.Range("AA3").Value).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next j
d = d + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

The macro call-order for the 'Update Revisions' button is as follows:

```
Sub MakeNewSheet()
Sheets.Add.Name = "Revisions"
End Sub

Sub copyRevisions()
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show
Sheet2.Range("AJ1").Value = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set x = ThisWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open(Sheet2.Range("AJ1").Value)
y.Sheets("Revisions").Range("A1:B" & lastRow).Copy
x.Sheets("Revisions").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
y.Close
End Sub


Sub updateRevs()
Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set r = Sheets("Revisions")
Dim d
d = 1
Dim j As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = r.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until IsEmpty(r.Range("A" & j))
For j = 1 To LastRow
    If r.Range("A" & d).Value = i.Range(j, 8).Value Then
        r.Range("B" & d).Copy
        i.Range(j, Sheet2.Range("AA3").Value).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next j
d = d + 1
Loop
End Sub

Sub deleteRevSheet()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Revisions").Delete
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated (even to say that it's possible or not in VBA!)

Thanks!

Updated working code, which probably requires fine-tuning:

```
Sub updateRevisions()
Dim i As Worksheet
Dim r As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRowSheets As Long
Set i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("000 MODELS, ACAD...")
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revisions")
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim e As Long
Dim check() As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim j As Integer
j = 1
Dim Col As Long
Col = Sheet2.Range("AB1").Value


LastRow = r.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowSheets = i.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

With Sheet1.Range("H51:H" & LastRowSheets)
ReDim check(j)
    For Each cell In r.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        check(j) = cell
            For e = LBound(check()) To UBound(check())
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=check(j), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                Rng.Offset(0, Col).Value = r.Cells(j + 1, "B").Value
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
                End If
            Next e
        j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve check(j)
Next
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for the elaborate post. Yet, I was unable to see the immanent question within. Could you please help me? Is the code working or not? If it is not working then please elaborate on the error messages that you get. If your code is incomplete and requires more code to accomplish additional tasks then you're probably in the wrong place as this site does not offer free code-writing services. If you have working code which requires merely tweaking then you should try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). So, which one is it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ralph. The first section of code in my edited post 'updateRevs' is not working, but the rest is and is just there for context of what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The sub `updateRevs` cannot work due to a few problems:

1. You declare `j` to be a range but then use it as a number.
2. The line where you are setting `LastRow` is not explicit and should include the sheet (`r.Rows.Count`).
3. The `Do Until` loop will never end because `j` is just going from 1 to the `LastRow` (which still contains data). So, here is an endless loop making the code run forever. I am not quite sure what you want to achieve here. Hence I do not know what to suggest as an improvement.
4. You used sometimes `Range` with two numbers to reference a cell. Yet, this is only possible with `Cells`. So, I changed a few of those to `Cells`. Yet, the reference here is `Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber)`. So, you might want to review these changes.

Here is the resulting code after these changes:

```
Sub updateRevs()

Dim d As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Worksheet
Dim r As Worksheet

d = 1
Set i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revisions")

LastRow = r.Range("A" & r.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until IsEmpty(r.Range("A" & j))
    For j = 1 To LastRow
        If r.Range("A" & d).Value = i.Cells(j, 8).Value Then
            r.Range("B" & d).Copy
            i.Cells(j, Sheet2.Range("AA3").Value).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next j
    d = d + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

<sub>As mentioned before this code will result in an endless loop and will have to be further adjusted. Most likely you can remove the loop altogether. Yet, I do not know what `d = d + 1` is for?!</sub>

<sub>Note also that this "answer" is more of a collection of hints to get you in the right direction (rather than a complete answer). This is due to the fact that it is currently not possible for me to see what you want to achieve with your loop.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ralph. As you can probably tell I'm relatively unskilled with VBA! Upon taking your advice, and some intensive Googling  I've now gotten it working. I'll add the code to the original post.

Comment: I am glad to hear that I've been able to help you figure out the correct code. Feel free to upvote my answer. When editing your original post, please don't make the mistake of removing your original post. This is still necessary to show future site visitors the original problem. Rather expand upon your post and **add** to the bottom a section with the newly updated code (which works).